# Is it a honor or disgrace to be the first host to a Trill symbiont?

Tags: star-trek, aliens

The great benefit of having a symbiont is having access to its memories and therefore access to a vast repertoire of knowledge and experience. So, basically, being the first host to a symbiont is, as I understand, not as beneficial as having an old symbiont. On the other hand, the symbiont survives quite a while with its memories of the first host.

So, in Trill society, is it considered a special honor to be selected first host to a symbiont or is it more a degradation to other hosts? I am aware that it is mostly considered an honor to be a host in Trill society and the rules to be joined are very strict. So, the question is more within joined Trills, is it something to boast with or something to keep a secret?

Comment: I haven't read it, but a reddit thread suggest [The Lives of Dax](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Lives_of_Dax) might provide some insight.

Comment: @Jontia Thx, I'll have a look

Comment: Who would win in a fight to the death, a Go'auld symbiote or a Trill? Would the Tok'ra condemn the battle or cheer?

Comment: @JohnO - A go'auld symbiote would be the immediate winner. Not only are they vicious, but they can emit toxins that will kill the other symbiote.

Comment: Hmm... are we talking Queens? If so, I would pick the Bluegill Mother. She can release bluegills and take over additional hosts, possibly including the Go'auld's host as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Being a symbiote's first host is probably best described as a *vocation*. The individual will spend the remainder of their life in service of the symbiote, it doesn't attract much cachet and there aren't even any particular benefits to the individual.

> Elma was a year ahead of Moll, but until they were assigned to the same Quad, she had never seen the Holt woman. And Moll made it a point to notice everything. **As the first host for the Enor symbiont, it was her duty to provide a solid foundation of experiences**, as well as a wide-ranging understanding of the numerous alien races that inhabited the Alpha Quadrant.
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: The Best and the Brightest](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Best_and_the_Brightest)</sup></sub>

The symbiote carries some vague shared memories with the other symbiotes that it shared a pool with, but doesn't bring much to the party.

> **Since Moll was a first host, she didn’t have the memories—except of the pool and some sort of common mental bond that all the symbionts shared before joining.** But she did have the strange sensations, feeling different than she used to be, yet not anything in particular.
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: The Best and the Brightest](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Best_and_the_Brightest)</sup></sub>

Jadzia gives us an overview of the way in which first hosts are viewed by Trill society

> “Moll is the first host for Enor. **Her life will be the moral and ethical foundation for every succeeding host. For those of you who are joined, you know what I’m talking about.”** Moll never remembered seeing Jadzia so serious. **“The success of every symbiont relationship rests in part on the ability of the first host to establish a foundation that is both inclusive yet solid.** That takes constant self-questioning, and inevitably some doubt about one’s own choices. And I’ve never known anyone better at self-examination than Moll.”
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: The Best and the Brightest](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Best_and_the_Brightest)</sup></sub>

The fact that your entire life is on display for another person (with no filter) means that those with the most exhibitionist traits are supposedly the most keen to chose a first hosting. Dax seems to think this is amusing.

> Keiko hesitated, but Dax had laid the groundwork for her to feel comfortable enough to ask, "Don't you find it intimidating at times? I mean, I would feel as if someone were always looking over my shoulder, knowing that the next hosts will have access to all of my memories." "It's true that most initiates have a strong streak of the exhibitionist in them." Dax laughed at Keiko's sudden blush. "That's why politicians and artists are usually willing to be the first hosts for young symbionts."
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: The Tempest](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tempest_(novel))</sup></sub>